# What to do when user answers multiple questions with same (low quality) answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, duplicate-answers

When reviewing a couple of late answers I came across 2 answers from the same user that were exactly the same. When checking the users page I saw that he had 4 answers, all of the answers are the same:

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22064400/2134785)
[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22064279/2134785)
[Answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22064184/2134785)
[Answer 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22064059/2134785)

What is right way to deal with these answers? Should I flag with needs moderator attention and add all the answers in the description or is there something else I could do?

Comment: Flag one of those posts with the "other" and explain clearly what is going on. A mod will look into it and *do the needful* :)

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ, I believe the phrase we're looking for here is *do the needful*.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ Thnx for the tip, answer is flagged!^^

Comment: I checked the answers. They are downvoted, but they can be same, because, the answers are on same type of questions. All four questions are asking for same thing, in somewhat different language then others. The questions can also be flagged for duplicate.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian - Actually I was about to answer this question (it is still in my draft). But I found the duplicate question where Bill has mentioned almost everything what I was going to post. And if you read Bill's answer correctly; he has mentioned the reason of the deletion of the duplicate answers which was due to *flag*.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest flag the answers and describe the reason as well to the moderator. I am sure it will work.